# Serving protected files using Django through DigtalOcean and Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean, file-system-storage

I am going to use to DigitalOcean Droplet and want to configure it for serving protected files like pictures, mp3 and videos with Nginx.

**Questions:**

- Is it like I serve my file as FileSystemStorage on my local computer with setting up all permissions related thing?
- It will serve after payment process will complete. All functionality was implemented on localhost and it works well:

  ```
  from django.db import models
  from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

  class ProductFile(models.Model):
      file = models.FileField(
          upload_to=uploade_protected_file,
          storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PROTECTED_ROOT)
      )
  ```

  Do this same type of setup work on DigitalOcean as well?

Comment: In what way are these files "protected"?

Comment: Like it will serve after payment process will complete. :)